# How can I get top 10 results from Elastic search using rest queries with the max hit documents?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch

I want to get the top 10 documents\rows where these rows should be ordered with most recently and multiple times accessed docs on top.
here's what I tried:

```
{
    "size": 10,
    "query": {
        "range": {
            "searchDate": {
                "gte": "DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30)"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "top_tags": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "searchDate"
                    },
                    "aggs": {
                        "top_otf_hits": {
                            "top_hits": {
                                "sort": [
                                    {
                                        "searchDate": {
                                            "order": "desc"
                                        }
                                    }
                                ],
                                "_source": {
                                    "includes": [
                                        "origin",
                                        "destination"
                                    ]
                                },
                                "size": 1
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please add your efforts here

Comment: Added the Rest query to question which results in bad request.
Basically i want to get the documents for last one month and then need to filter 10 top hit documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{
    "from": 0,
    "size": 0,
    "sort": [{
        "searchDate": "desc"
    }, "_score"],
    "query": {
        "range": {
            "searchDate": {
                "gte": "2018-02-28",
                "lte": "2018-03-05",
                "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
            }
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "frequent": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "tripKey"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "top_otf_hits": {
                    "top_hits": {
                        "sort": [{
                            "searchDate": {
                                "order": "desc"
                            }
                        }],
                        "_source": {
                            "include": ["*"]
                        },
                        "size": 1
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```